# In PyGame, I need to set the coordinates of an image as variables (x, y)

Tags: python, pygame, coordinates

Code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))

blockImg = pygame.image.load('Rectangle.png')

block_rect = blockImg.get.rect()

x = block_rect.x   
/or x = block_rect.left/

y = block_rect.y   
/or y = block_rect.top/

print(x, y)
```

Problem

When I made a bit of code which moves the image across the screen at a steady rate and constantly updates the x and y of the image, it will only print out "(0, 0)" as if the image was at the top left of the window and not moving

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Side note: Python comment is # not /

Comment: Every time you update `block_rect.x` you need to re-assign it to `x`. Same with `y`. This is called "pass by value" instead of "pass by reference", so it copies the number rather than making a reference to the value that's getting updated.

Comment: Where's your position updating code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to know what you did wrong here since you didn't post the blit code.

If I had to guess, you probably haven't updated the x, y variables you are using when you are blitting to the screen.  They don't automatically update themselves, you have to set

```
x = block_rect.left
```

each frame.

However here is some minimal working code that does what you are expecting.

```
import pygame

BGCOLOR = (100,100,100)
SCREENWIDTH = 600
SCREENHEIGHT = 400

pygame.init()

display = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

block_img = pygame.image.load('Rectangle.png')
block_rect = block_img.get_rect()

#set velocity variable for updating position of rect
#make sure you do this before you go into the loop
velocity = 1

while 1:
    #fill in display
    display.fill(BGCOLOR)

    #pygame event type pygame.QUIT is activated when you click the X in the topright 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            #if you don't call pygame.quit() sometimes python will crash
            pygame.quit()
            #exit loop
            break

    #reverses velocity variable if rect goes off screen
    if block_rect.right > SCREENWIDTH:
        velocity = -velocity
    elif block_rect.left < 0:
        velocity = -velocity

    #update blocks position based on velocity variable
    block_rect.left += velocity

    #variables representing the x, y position of the block
    x, y = block_rect.left, block_rect.top
    display.blit(block_img, (x,y))

    #display.blit(block_img, block_rect) would also work here
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: I've figured it out, I was forgetting to update the position every frame, thank you very much for your help